# Code coverage for Classes with only final static string Variables

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class which contains only public static final strings how do i write a test class to cover this code?

```
public class SFA_MobileConstants {

 public static final string ERROR='ERROR';
 public static final string FAIL='FAIL';
 public static final string SUCCESS='SUCCESS';
 public static final string RECSAVEMSG='Record saved';

}


@istest
public class testconstants {

     public testMethod static void testSFA_MobileConstants(){

  System.assertEquals(SFA_MobileConstants.ERROR,SFA_MobileConstants.ERROR);     
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should find that if you are testing the code that references these strings they should be covered. Otherwise add a test method to the class that references those strings.

```
public with sharing class TestStrings {

    public static final String TEST = 'MyString';

    @IsTest
    public static void testStrings()
    {
         System.assertEquals(TEST, TEST);
    }
}
```

If your variables and tests are in different classes, just be sure to qualify the class name.

```
public with sharing class TestStrings2 {

    @IsTest
    public static void testStrings()
    {
        System.assertEquals(TestString.TEST, TestString.TEST);
    }
}
```

In this case you really are just gaining coverage, as we expect the platform behaviour to work and of course provide consistently the strings we assign. So while you could do the same without the assert, it just feels wrong from a best practice point of view. And of course would raise the eye of the security scanner.

[image]

Comment: I tried but i cannot assign again values as its a final variable and simply assigning these into another variable not helping either

Comment: Ok I assumed the strings are defined as in my answer, perhaps if you can publish a sample in your answer I can better understand what you mean.

Comment: Mine is in separate class and the test code is in different class

Comment: Andrew thanks for reply.I have given the code in my question

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer to show a test from another class referencing your static final variables from another.

Comment: cool..trying ..looks like asserting calls those ..keeping finger crossed!

Comment: Weird .I have updated my test code too in question.Its not covering and also no red lines also the test editor showing thats its not covered ,Weird.But +1 from my side for the effort.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, it does however both in the IDE and in the browser (after clicking Run Tests button) report 100% code coverage. It maybe that they are being cover by the fact the class is now referenced by a test and thus the static initialisers fire during the test context. To confirm this i added public static final ANOTHER = makeAString(); which calls a static method, I didn't explicitly call this method from the test and it still covered it. What problem is it that your thinking this is causing you btw?

Comment: i guess its some bug.This keeps happening.Last time even my comments in code were marked red and when i deployed to other instance it disappeared .So a small bug

Comment: Yes that does sound odd, I also have heard of issues in this area of reporting. Just make sure your on the latest API version as possible and if you can reproduce it, raise a SF case. Sorry I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks for help.No issues .I know its weird .Thanks again for all good work and help

Answer (score 2):

Please add a constructor like this:

`public SFA_MobileConstants() {}`

It will fix your issues.